# My microphone has no 1-channel options. Can I get them and how?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, recording, control-panel

Windows 7 user on a Cybertron Borg-Q (a very iffy computer overall). In control panel, my recording device (plugged into the red port on the front of my computer) has no "2 channel" options and this is sort of annoying me because the left channel records nothing but a faint crackling noise.

[image: screenshot 1]
        [image: screenshot 2]

My driver appears to be by AMD but the publisher of the recording device's driver says "Microsoft." 
All I want to do is find a way to make the recording device record both sides the way it records the right side, or to make it "1 channel." Is this possible outside of the settings in individual software? Can I install a replacement driver that will work with my soundcard?

Comment: Provide your computer make / model.

Comment: ok done - Cybertron Borg-Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a hardware problem to me. On your Tip Ring Sleeve(TRS) connector the tip is left and the ring is right. If you are getting a cracking noise on the left side and no audio, the connector is activating the tip connector in the computer but not receiving audio. I think there is a break somewhere in the Tip cable.

1) Unplug and plug the Mic into the laptop a bunch of times, there could be dirt on the connectors inside the laptop. This is called exercising connector and could remove some dirt.

2)Try the Mic out on another computer to see if you get the same result?

Comment: I tried another, battery-run microphone in my computer (only one I had to test with) and it came in the same on both sides, so yeah I guess it is the mic or cable I'm using. The 48v amp I'm supposed to have hasn't arrived yet and I just have an XLR to 1/8" jack adapter running to the computer. It's only getting the 5v from the soundcard and googling my issue didn't tell me if should expect the left side to behave that way without the amp. I was only wondering if I could make the right side mirror the left within Windows. Thanks for your answer though, now I know it's not the PC.

Comment: With out phantom power (48V) that mic won't work, it's like trying to start a car off an AAA battery. What you want to do is pan the Mic to the right side and mono the feed. unfortunately, the windows mic setting don't allow for this, what program are you wanting to record in? You might be able to adjust the mic setting in that program.

Comment: yeah I got the amp and it's good now -  sorry

Comment: No worries, the best way to learn is through the experience of something breaking on you.